# Analytic Spaces and Formal Duals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, complex-geometry, equivalence-of-categories

On nLab, the authors characterize an analytic space as locally modeled on formal duals of sub-algebras of power series algebras with desirable convergence properties. I have seen the definition for (complex) analytic spaces, and while I understand the basic construction, I'm having trouble understanding this idea of "formal duality" in a more general context.

For example, in scheme theory, there is the usual adjunction between $\operatorname{Spec}$ and $\Gamma$ restricting to an equivalence $\mathsf{Aff}\leftrightharpoons \mathsf{CRing}^\text{op}$.

Somewhat similarly, the functor $C^\infty(-):\mathsf{SmoothMfd}\longrightarrow \mathsf{Alg}_\mathbb{R}^\text{op}$ can be shown to be fully faithful, and so restricts to an equivalence into the (full) subcategory of $\mathsf{Alg}_\mathbb{R}^\text{op}$ of objects in the image of $C^\infty(-)$.

On the nLab page about analytic spaces, their hyperlink associated to "formal duals" leads to their page on Isbell duality. This leads me to believe (given my limited knowledge of category theory) that the two examples above are specific instantiations of this duality, but I'm having trouble making that connection.

Returning to the first paragraph, is there a similar adjunction to $\operatorname{Spec}\dashv \Gamma$ for analytic (or even locally ringed) spaces which restricts to an equivalence of local model spaces? I know this post has around three questions wrapped up in the body; I really appreciate any help or comments! Thank you.

Comment: “Formally” here means “in form only”, or in other words, “without substance”. As it happens, this is not actually true and these dualities can be realised concretely…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the pattern is that the category of geometric objects locally modeled on algebraic objects from some category $A$ is generated under certain colimits by $A^{op},$ which is the category of formal duals of objects of $A.$ The manifold case is unusual since every manifold is, so to speak, affine. So the analytic space case will be much more like schemes. I won’t try to answer the last question because you should try to hone in on a specific definition of analytic space you’re interested in. As you can start to see here, there are a lot of very different options once you get beyond $\mathbb C:$ https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Berkovich+space

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on the category of geometric objects being generated under certain colimits by $A^\text{op}$? Is this pattern analogous to the gluing process for schemes via coequalizer diagrams? I imagine there is some duality (the global sections functor is a right adjoint, so cocontinuous) with the equalizer sheaf condition in the "algebraic" realm, but this could be too hasty a comparison. I'll take a look at the link!

Comment: @LiminalSpace The gluing process for schemes is exactly the right analogy, yes.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted your answer. For any future comments, I should specify that I'm considering the global sections functor on $\mathsf{LRS}$, which is (as I've just realized) a left adjoint to $\operatorname{Spec}$.